# how to update game state by using pixels as input?

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I'm currently writing a program using keras (python 3) to play a game similar to Atari games, only in this one there are objects moving in the screen in different angles and directions (in most of Atari games I've encountered the objects you need to shoot are static). The agent's aim is to shoot them. My Input is the pixels on the screen (and those are the states). after I get the screenshot I convert it into a pixels matrix, only I'm not sure how to efficiently get a new state and how to process the state's info. if anyone have a recommendation for an article or a book which could guide me how to efficiently use my information from the screenshot, I would be very grateful.

Thank you

Comment: The most effective way to use this information is through a CNN, which should cope with this very well. Research CNN's, you can easily do them in keras IIRC